VMware SRM with Different vCenter Versions will work?
We currently have two sites where SRM version 8.6.0 is in use, and both sites are running vCenter version 7.0.3. We are planning to upgrade one of the vCenters to version 8.0.
Could you please confirm whether SRM 8.6.0 will continue to function correctly between two sites with different vCenter versions (7.0.3 and 8.0)?

Yes, but you’ll have to look at the compatibility matrix to verify if 7.0.3 and 8.0.0 are compatible with one another

Broadcom support portal may changed many things. That will be complicated to find out

I found the comparability matrix fairly fast.

“Site Recovery Manager 8.6 is compatible with vCenter Server 7.0 and later versions” directly from the documentation

I found the solution from the VMware site. Product Interoperability Matrix has provide the compatibility list. This is the URL to check the compatibility.
https://interopmatrix.broadcom.com/Interoperability
